# Include node_modules folder when running npm pack

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a module with a folder named someDir which has node modules. When I try to npm pack, it includes someDir but does not recursively include node_modules folders inside someDir. Is there a way I can include node_modules folders using npm pack. I do not want to use npm bundledDependencies just want the node_modules to be included in someDir folder.